# Is it okay for combi setup to be shared between all the radiators and taps in the house except the kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe, combi

The new flat I moved into has a quirk about it's water loop

[image: Weird Piping Scheme]

I realized that when I take a shower. All the radiators immediately go cold and the showerheards heat sometimes gets low only for me to open the hot tap all the way for a few secods to fix it which confirms that radiator loop is connected to the rest of the taps in the house with only the kitchen sink having dedicated water pipes

I also find it weird that water from kitchen sinks hot water tap is opaque gray if I open it too much but showerhead gives clean water.

From what I read online, there are supposed to be seperate pipes for every tap and radiator in someones house but I guess whoever that did  plumbing of this house was a cheapskate but I wonder if this is common happening in old retrofit systems or combi setups in general. Could this cause issues or anything like that? Due to economic issues in my country (Turkey) and family I am planning to simply close all valves of all the radiators in my flat before showering to mitigate this as opposed to expensive piping job.

Comment: Where in the world are you? The answer to your questions is going to be determined by local regulations, but we're left guessing. The use of "flat" indicates UK or a former UK colony, but that's still a pretty big list of places.

Comment: @FreeMan well I am in Turkey but the main issue is that there is hyperinflation (1 Euro was 20 Liras recently and now 16 or so) and quite frankly it doesn't change the fact that we can't afford anything.